# Using MOQ for unit tests of business logic

Tags: c#, moq

I've been asked to write a Unit test for some new business logic and am not convinced this is something MOQ can use. Looking for some advise on this from someone familiar with MOQ.

New business logic has been added to a `Save()` method where within the `Save()`, we query the database and "Abandon" proceeding (now obsolete) data.

```cs
public class Event
{
    public int EventId = 0;
    public string Status = "Ready";
    public int ReferenceId = 0;

    public void Save()
    {
        // Update the Subject event
        var save_to_database_successful = false;
        var obj = db.Events.Find(this.EventId);
        obj.Status = "Complete";
        obj.SubmitChanges();
        save_to_database_successful = true;

        if(save_to_database_successful == true)
        {
            // Query the database, find and mark obsolete Events as `Abandoned`
            var q = from o in db.Events
                    where o.ReferenceId = this.ReferenceId
                          && o.EventId != this.EventId
                    select o;
            q.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.Status = "Abandoned";
            });
            db.SubmitChange();
        }
    }

}
```

I don't see how we can write a MOQ unit test to confirm that proceeding `Events` was marked as `Abandoned`. Am I right?

*Note:*
For brevity I've purposefully left out the EF objects and database classes. Just know that the `db` variable is being injected into the code elsewhere and correctly populated.

Comment: That looks like EF code and it means mocking the DbContext, which is possible, but a mess IMO.   There are quite a few examples out there to draw on, but the fundamentals can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN Applicable for EF6 and Core. Personally if I'm going to be unit testing around an EF DbContext this is a good reason to consider implementing a Repository pattern. (A bit cleaner separation than DbContext + DbSet)

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Do we avoid encountering the same problem even after implementing a Repository pattern? My goal for the unit test is to confirm that the prior (now obsolete) Events are abandoned. If the unit test were querying a real database, I could `Save()` and then query the database to confirm the desired outcome using an `Assert.IsTrue()` confirming that the `Count()` of the Abandoned Events matches a number I am expecting. My problem is that I don't understand how to replicate the same assertion using MOQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall though the code example you have is somewhat confusing as it looks like  Event should be an entity, but it is not written in a way that it would behave as a regular tracked entity. A tracked entity for instance does not need a "Save" method doing what your code does. A tracked entity is simply updated and at some point the DbContext that is tracking it calls `SaveChanges` and the values are persisted. This Event class is either written in a way where it is an Entity that is expected to be always in a detached state, or cross-cutting concerns where it is serving as a detached container class or a tracked entity. (If it is the same class as the "Event" entity that db.Events is)

However, relating to mocking: The first rule of mocking involves understanding what you are mocking to ensure that you are testing the right thing, and don't end up testing the mock. So whether you use a Repository pattern or mocking a DbSet, the first thing is understanding what is mocked, why, and how it will be validated. Using a mocked DbContext and DbSet for instance the code under test needs to be fed a Mock for each dependency, so in your case that will start with the reference to "db" which would be a DbContext. From the code provided it isn't clear where this is declared and initialized, but it needs to be injected for a mock to work for instance via the constructor:

```
public Event(AppDbContext db)
{
    this.db = db;
}
```

Either that or property injection:

```
public AppDbContext db { get; set; }
```

... where the calling code can inject the DbContext.

What won't work is where the DbContext is scoped in the code you want to test: for instance:

```
private readonly AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();
```

In this case you need to change it either to be injected in the constructor, or  at worst, expose a means for tests to inject it. For example in legacy code-bases that don't have injected dependencies, changing something like this:

```
private readonly AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();
```

to this:

```
private AppDbContext _db = new AppDbContext();
internal AppDbContext db 
{
    get => _db;
    set { _db = value; }
}
```

This way a test can new up an Event and use the Setter to set the "db" reference to a mock. In this case I use an internal member which involves setting an InternalsVisibleTo configuration from your assembly under test to the unit test assembly so it can see/use internal members.

Once we know the code under test can accept a mocked DbContext we create the necessary Mocks and set them up to serve the expected needs of the test and code under test. One useful Nuget package for testing DbSets or `IQueryable` code is MockQueryable.Moq (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq/1.1.0)
This will help avoid problems when working with `async` operations, and is just in general a good option to get comfortable with when returning Linq query results.

In your case with a DbContext and DbSet you are going to want to create a `Mock<AppDbContext>` where "AppDbContext" is your application's DbContext class, then a `Mock<DbSet<Event>>` for the Events DbSet accessed by your code under test. It is this second Mock, the DbSet, where you are going to want to substitute with a `MockQueryable<Event>`. This will be a known set of data you construct as a plain-old `IEnumerable<Event>` then call `.BuildMock()`

So for instance if we want a test scenario that returns no matching records then:

```
var expectedResults = new List<Event>().BuildMock();

var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Event>>();
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Event>>()
    .Setup(m => m.Provider)
    .Returns(expectedResults.Provider);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Event>>()
    .Setup(m => m.Expression)
    .Returns(expectedResults.Expression);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Event>>()
    .Setup(m => m.ElementType)
    .Returns(expectedResults.ElementType);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Event>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => expectedResults.GetEnumerator());

mockDbContext.Setup(m => m.Events)
    .Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
```

I'm not 100% sure the above code is complete as I haven't looked at mocking DbSets for some time, I just recall it being a fair bit messier than just a Repository method that returns `IQueryable`.

For cases where you want an expected set, load them into the expectedResults List. MockQueryable isn't required if you only use synchronous methods like `ToList()` etc. but it is recommended so that it can be used with asynchronous methods as well. (`ToListAsync()`)

So in your case you can write tests where there are one or more  expected results that are returned by your mock DbSet which is returned by the mock DbContext.Events, then after your code executes, you can inspect the instances in your ExpectedResults to see if the expected records had their values updated, and any in the collection that *shouldn't* be updated, weren't, for example.

The repository pattern can simplify the mocking process. For instance I use a repository pattern that returns `IQueryable`. I'm not a fan of things like Generic repositories or otherwise scoping a Repository to a single Entity type but rather scoping it to serve a Controller or Service, however the principle is the same. The benefit of a Repository is that it can simplify testing, where mocking DbSets and such you can just mock the Repository method to return the MockQueryable wrapped List.

You can also use the mock of the DbContext to assert whether SaveChanges is called or not. For instance in some scenarios if nothing has changed it shouldn't be called so having a test that asserts that scenario. Mocks serve two purposes, to provide predictable results (whether result data, or throwing exceptions, etc.) when they are accessed in place of "live" classes, and to help validate/report back what calls have been made to assert what should be called was called, and what shouldn't be called, wasn't. In Moq this is done using the `.Verify()` method.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thank you for such a in depth answer. I should have clarified that I am using EF, but to query the database, populating the `Event` with the query result. I am using EF for the CUD operations on the database. The business object itself does not inherit or extend any EF objects. And I've left out the EF code that populates `db` for brevity purposes. Whilst I can appreciate there are other ways to implement this, I am confined by the constraints of an existing system where I am a bit limited which how much of the code I can refactor.

Comment: If I seem confused by what might appear to be a straightforward answer, I'm at a loss how (without database operations) I can (within the TestMethod) Assert that the business logic is working correctly. The code owner seems strict on wanting to use the MOQ framework, and I'm thinking it's not applicable or useful here because there is no shared context between the TestMethod and DAL. Within `Event.Save()` we're updating the subject Event and then querying the database for any correlated (now obsolete) events.

Comment: Without querying the actual database (i.e. `select * from dbo.Events where ReferenceId = @val`) and confirming that all of the other Events are abandoned, how else can a unit test be written? From what I've read on the MOQ framework, it doesn't appear possible without refactoring our code under test and that database operations is the only option available to us in this situation.

Comment: Your expected results collection would contain both the Event you expect the code to request to complete, and related events that the code will retrieve to set to abandoned, and possibly another unrelated event or two for good measure. When the code requests db.Events from the Mock, it gets the MockQueryable pointing to your Events collection. To validate after the method call happens, check the state of the Event objects in your expectedResults list. The one it should have picked should be set, the ones you expect to be abandoned should be changed, and the others left unchanged.

Comment: So in the collection I might have the one record with the requested ID, 2 with the expected ReferenceId with an expected initial status, then 1 or 2 with a different reference ID with some status. After the code runs I check the requested ID event has the correct status, the ones with the ReferenceID are abandoned, and the others weren't touched. It gets more complex if you are testing code that adds or removes items, your mocked DbSet has to be setup for those actions in that scenario. The goal to keep in mind though is to test the logic, not that the DbContext actually returns data.